# Imagemagick setup

Tags: image-processing, drupal-6, imagemagick

my employers have a requirement to upload very large hi-res images. Ordinarily uploading such images does not work.

I was told using **ImageMagick** would help shift the image processing burden to the Linux server instead of php (so I don't have to set the php max_memory to some ridiculous level).

Anyway, I followed this tutorial: http://thewichitacomputerguy.com/blog/how-enable-install-imagemagick-drupal
I got the following response:

```
* warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/bin/convert) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs:/tmp) in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs/includes/image.imagemagick.inc on line 55.

* No file /usr/bin/convert could be found. PHP's open_basedir security restriction is set to /var/www/vhosts/mysite.co.uk/httpdocs:/tmp, which may be interfering with the attempts to locate ImageMagick.
```

I have determined the `/usr/bin/convert` file definitely exists on the server but I am at a loss regarding how to proceed.

Can you guys help a drupaler out?

Comment: I think the answer is in your error message.  Looks like you are on a shared hosting environment and you can not exec() outside of your root or something like that.  EC2 is wicked cheap and gives you a VPS all your own.  Then you can exec() to your hearts content. =D

Comment: I tried EC2 but I could not understand their price structure at the time. Can you please tell me how much you pay for your VPS?
BTW, the site in question is on a dedicated server.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on shared hosting, you will need to speak with your provider.  If you administer your server, you will need to edit your php.ini to allow open_basedir access to your imagemagick directory.

Comment: The drupal site is actually on a dedicated server.
Can you tell me how I might provide such a php.ini file strictly for the site and what needs to go into the file, please ?

Comment: Please forgive mere mortals like me who don't rival your experience. It's what forums are for I think - to get HELP!?

Thanks for the suggestion. Appreciate it.

Comment: Sisko, help is provided on a volunteer basis here.  You are asking very, very basic questions that half an hour of reading on php.net or a google search would answer.  If you do not like the answers you have gotten that's fine, but please do not cop an attitude.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagik always give me a hard time...

That tutorial you cited isn't the way that I typically go about installing it.  I think that installing ImageMagik to your /includes folder could be related to the problem. If you want to continue to try to make that work, then try configuring ImageMagik in the Drupal admin pages to look in the right place:
**admin/settings/imageapi/config**

(assuming you've got the [ImageAPI](http://drupal.org/project/imageapi) module)

If you can't make the magik happen in there.. I'd try installing ImageMagik with SSH (assuming you've got shell access, because this is a dedicated server)

To do that get yourself [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)

Then figure out what distro of linux you are running (check your host's forum, or ask them.. or try [this](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/miscellaneous/85699-how-find-out-distro-im-running.html)) and run a command like this:

```
apt-get install imagemagick
```

or like this..

```
yum install imagemagik
```

Once you get it you'll just need to test it and set up the Drupal image handling with [ImageCache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache)

A few cool related modules (once you get it working):

- [ImageField focus](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield_focus)
- [Avatar crop](http://drupal.org/project/avatarcrop)